# Replace a char in array of string when IF statement is satisfied

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a method where an array of `char` "s"  is entered along with 2 other `char`s `char1` and `char2`, this method called `substitute` will then search through the array and if it spots an instance of `char1` FOLLOWED by "!", it will replace that `char1` with `char2`.

However, when testing my method it doesn't seem to do that, the `if` statement is never satisfied.

Please help.

**substitute method**

```
void substitute(char* s, char c1, char c2)
{
   int n = strlen(s);
   for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
   {
       if(s[i] == c1 && s[i+1] == '!')
       {
         s[i] = c2;
       }
       i++;
   }
}
```

**test input**

```
char s[] = "la!bellabella!bel";
char c1  = 'a';
char c2  = 'x';

substitute(s,c1,c2);
cout << s << endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code increments `i` twice - once as part of `for` statement, and again in the body of the loop. The effect is that you only check even-numbered characters, skipping every other character.